# Generating a tuple in Maple

Tags: algorithms, software

I am trying to generate a 2 tuple using maple. Can anyone give me the command to generate this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by a 2-tuple? If the two values you want to put into it are called `x` and `y`, then you can create a

- *sequence* as `x, y`
- *list* as `[x, y]`
- *set* as `{x, y}`
- *Vector* as `<x, y>`
- *Array* as `Array([x, y])`
- *table* as e.g. `table([1 = x, 2 = y])` (or use something else as keys - or use `x` and `y` as keys and something else as values)
- *record* as e.g. `Record(x, y)`
- *mutable set* as `MutableSet(x, y)` (I don't believe this is documented, so you're on your own for forward compatibility)
- *deque* as `DEQueue(x, y)` (same remarks as for the mutable set)
- *unevaluated function call* as e.g. `f(x, y)`

Each of these can be used as a 2-tuple (with some fantasy). What do you want to do with the tuple?